# Is content inside a <noscript> tag indexed by search indexes?

Tags: seo, html, noscript

Is content inside a `<noscript>` ([HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#h-18.3.1), [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-noscript-element)) tag indexed by search engines?

(*Inspired by [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1683/best-way-to-stop-a-country-dropdown-from-affecting-google-seo)*)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did a little research and it sounds like there is a lot to the `<noscript>` tag.  Here is what I found:

1. Google does look at the data inside of the `<noscript>` tag
2. Spammers and black hats have abused the `<noscript>` tag before.  So even when Google uses the `<noscript>` tag to determine search results it isn't one of the stronger rules.
3. Google seems to be currently index the text inside of the `<noscript>` tag for results but it appears to turn that on and off, see here, http://www.webmasterworld.com/google/3122771.htm
4. Google will follow links inside of the `<noscript>` tag but it will not send PR to the pages linked from within the `<noscript>` tag

Also, according to this document, http://searchengineland.com/google-io-new-advances-in-the-searchability-of-javascript-and-flash-but-is-it-enough-19881, Google prefers the text within the noscript to match the test within your JavaScript.  The goal of using `<noscript>` to provide graceful degradation.  This article also makes it sound like Google can now index JavaScript fairly well which means abusing the `<noscript>` tag is a bad idea but that there is nothing wrong with using it.

Answer (score 10):

It's indexed by Google. Try searching for

```
site:www.flickr.com "to take full advantage of flickr, you should use a javascript-enabled browser"
```

Google also adds "About 58,400,000 results (0.22 seconds)".

Comment: Clever ..... :)